# FailedPreconditionError with custom Tensorflow 2 Model. Variable cannot be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have set up custom training and testing functions in my project so I can minutely customise the training process. I use k-fold cross-validation to evaluate my model. For whatever reason, the model trains correctly for the first fold, and then on the second in throws this error.

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:  Could not find variable _AnonymousVar13. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status=Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar13/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist. [[node test_model/dense_2/Tensordot/ReadVariableOp (defined at training_example.py:33) ]] [Op:__inference__train_step_1082]`

I have no idea what's happening. I assumed the error arose because of poor initialisation, so I `model.build()` with the input shape. I have tried initialising the graph's weights with blank tensor, too, but that didn't work. I have also reset the backend on the last line in case there was a conflict with names, but that doesn't do the trick.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.model_selection
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Mean, Precision, Recall
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam

n_splits = 5
batch_size = 16
n_epochs = 2
loss_function = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
optimiser_fn = Adam
metrics = [
    Mean(name='loss'),
    Precision(name='prec'),
    Recall(name='recall'),
]
learning_rate = 1e-2
dense_outputs = [10,10]
activation = 'relu'

class TestModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._dense_ops = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(o) for o in dense_outputs]
        self._output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        hidden = inputs
        for l in self._dense_ops:
            hidden = l(hidden)
        return self._output(hidden)

def _load_fold_sets_for_training(fold, fold_idcs, features, labels, batch_size):
    # Get the indices for the sets.
    train_idcs, validation_idcs, _ = fold_idcs[fold]

    # Get the training data and labels.
    training_data = features[train_idcs]
    training_labels = labels[train_idcs]

    # Load the training, validation and testing sets.
    training_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (training_data, training_labels)
    )
    training_set = training_set.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=False)

    validation_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (features[validation_idcs], labels[validation_idcs])
    )
    validation_set = validation_set.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=False)

    return training_set, validation_set

@tf.function
def _train_step(batch_samples, batch_labels):
    batch_predictions = model(batch_samples, training=True)

    loss = loss_function(batch_predictions, batch_labels)

    gradients = tf.gradients(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimiser.apply_gradients(
        zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables)
    )

    batch_predictions = tf.sigmoid(batch_predictions)

    metrics[0].update_state(loss)
    [m.update_state(batch_labels, batch_predictions) for m in metrics[1:]]


@tf.function
def _inference_step(batch_samples, batch_labels):
    batch_predictions = model(batch_samples, training=False)

    loss = loss_function(batch_predictions, batch_labels)

    batch_predictions = tf.sigmoid(batch_predictions)

    metrics[0].update_state(loss)
    [m.update_state(batch_labels, batch_predictions) for m in metrics[1:]]

# Generate dataset.
features = np.random.rand(15,1440,1)
labels = np.random.rand(15,1440)

# Set up splits.
kfold = sklearn.model_selection.KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True)
splits = []
for train_idcs, test_idcs in kfold.split(features):
    train_idcs, val_idcs = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(train_idcs)
    splits += [[train_idcs, val_idcs, test_idcs]]

fold = 0
while fold < n_splits:
    # Load datasets for fold.
    training_set, validation_set = _load_fold_sets_for_training(fold, splits, features, labels, batch_size)

    # Load model.
    model = TestModel()

    # Build model.
    model.build((1440, 1))

    # Initialise Adam optimiser.
    optimiser = optimiser_fn(learning_rate)

    epoch = 0
    while epoch < n_epochs:
        epoch += 1

        # Training.
        for batch_features, batch_labels in training_set: _train_step(batch_features, batch_labels)
        print(f'fold {fold}: epoch {epoch}:', ' '.join(f'train_{m.name}: {m.result():0.05f}' for m in metrics))

        # Validation.
        for batch_features, batch_labels in validation_set: _inference_step(batch_features, batch_labels)
        print(f'fold {fold}: epoch {epoch}:', ' '.join(f'val_{m.name}: {m.result():0.05f}' for m in metrics))

    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

    fold += 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the placement of the `_train_step` and `_inference_step`. If the two functions are redefined on every iteration of the fold, the error disappears and the model trains. I don't know why they must be redefined every step.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.model_selection
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Mean, Precision, Recall
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam

n_splits = 5
batch_size = 2
n_epochs = 2
loss_function = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
optimiser_fn = Adam
metrics = [
    Mean(name='loss'),
    Precision(name='prec'),
    Recall(name='recall'),
]
learning_rate = 1e-2
dense_outputs = [10, 10]
activation = 'relu'


class TestModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._dense_ops = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(o) for o in dense_outputs]
        self._output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        hidden = inputs
        for l in self._dense_ops:
            hidden = l(hidden)
        return self._output(hidden)


def _load_fold_sets_for_training(fold, fold_idcs, features, labels, batch_size):
    # Get the indices for the sets.
    train_idcs, validation_idcs, _ = fold_idcs[fold]

    # Get the training data and labels.
    training_data = features[train_idcs]
    training_labels = labels[train_idcs]

    # Load the training, validation and testing sets.
    training_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (training_data, training_labels)
    )
    training_set = training_set.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=False)

    validation_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (features[validation_idcs], labels[validation_idcs])
    )
    validation_set = validation_set.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=False)

    return training_set, validation_set


# Generate dataset.
features = np.random.rand(15, 1440, 1)
labels = np.random.rand(15, 1440)

# Set up splits.
kfold = sklearn.model_selection.KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True)
splits = []
for train_idcs, test_idcs in kfold.split(features):
    train_idcs, val_idcs = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(train_idcs)
    splits += [[train_idcs, val_idcs, test_idcs]]

fold = 0
while fold < n_splits:
    @tf.function
    def _train_step(batch_samples, batch_labels):
        batch_predictions = model(batch_samples, training=True)

        loss = loss_function(batch_predictions, batch_labels)

        gradients = tf.gradients(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimiser.apply_gradients(
            zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables)
        )

        batch_predictions = tf.sigmoid(batch_predictions)

        metrics[0].update_state(loss)
        [m.update_state(batch_labels, batch_predictions) for m in metrics[1:]]


    @tf.function
    def _inference_step(batch_samples, batch_labels):
        batch_predictions = model(batch_samples, training=False)

        loss = loss_function(batch_predictions, batch_labels)

        batch_predictions = tf.sigmoid(batch_predictions)

        metrics[0].update_state(loss)
        [m.update_state(batch_labels, batch_predictions) for m in metrics[1:]]


    # Load datasets for fold.
    training_set, validation_set = _load_fold_sets_for_training(fold, splits, features, labels,
                                                                batch_size)

    # Load model.
    model = TestModel()

    # Build model.
    model.build((1440, 1))

    # Initialise Adam optimiser.
    optimiser = optimiser_fn(learning_rate)

    epoch = 0
    while epoch < n_epochs:
        epoch += 1

        # Training.
        for batch_features, batch_labels in training_set: _train_step(batch_features,
                                                                      batch_labels)
        print(f'fold {fold}: epoch {epoch}:', ' '.join(f'train_{m.name}: {m.result():0.05f}' for
                                                       m in metrics))

        # Validation.
        for batch_features, batch_labels in validation_set: _inference_step(batch_features,
                                                                            batch_labels)
        print(f'fold {fold}: epoch {epoch}:', ' '.join(f'val_{m.name}: {m.result():0.05f}' for m
                                                       in metrics))

    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

    fold += 1
```